# Generator-expression, getting the same results of using append or extend in a for-loop

Tags: python, for-loop, append, extend, generator-expression

```
usingAppend = []; usingExtend = []; usingLC = []

d = {'pKey_b': 'vb1', 'pKey_e': 've1', 'pKey_c': 'vc1', 'pKey_a': 'va1', 'pKey_d': 'vd1'}
```

Using `append` in the `for-loop` gives a `list` with sublists

```
for k, v in sorted(d.iteritems()):
    usingAppend.append([k, v])
print '\n', usingAppend

'''
[
 ['pKey_a', 'va1'],
 ['pKey_b', 'vb1'],
 ['pKey_c', 'vc1'],
 ['pKey_d', 'vd1'],
 ['pKey_e', 've1']
]
'''
```

Using `extend` in the `for-loop` gives a single `list`

```
for k, v in sorted(d.iteritems()):
    usingExtend.extend((k, v))
print '\n', usingExtend

'''
['pKey_a', 'va1', 'pKey_b', 'vb1', 'pKey_c', 'vc1', 'pKey_d', 'vd1', 'pKey_e', 've1']
'''
```

Using this generator expression gives the same results as using `append` in a `for loop`, a `list` with sublists

```
usingLC = sorted([k, v] for k, v in d.iteritems())
print '\n', usingLC

'''
[
 ['pKey_a', 'va1'],
 ['pKey_b', 'vb1'],
 ['pKey_c', 'vc1'],
 ['pKey_d', 'vd1'],
 ['pKey_e', 've1']
]
'''
```

My question is, is there a way to set up the generator expression to give the same results as using `extend` in a for-loop

Comment: You have a generator expression, not a list comprehension. The same principles apply though.

Comment: I changed my post to say generator expression along with the tag, thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: @Michael you're allowed to [edit] your own posts :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use double looping:

```
[i for k, v in sorted(d.iteritems()) for i in (k, v)]
```

or

```
[i for item in sorted(d.iteritems()) for i in item]
```

or [`itertools.chain.from_iterable()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable):

```
from itertools import chain

list(chain.from_iterable(item for item in sorted(d.iteritems())))
```

although you could just use:

```
list(chain.from_iterable(sorted(d.iteritems())))
```

in these cases.

Demo:

```
>>> d = {'pKey_b': 'vb1', 'pKey_e': 've1', 'pKey_c': 'vc1', 'pKey_a': 'va1', 'pKey_d': 'vd1'}
>>> [i for k, v in sorted(d.iteritems()) for i in (k, v)]
['pKey_a', 'va1', 'pKey_b', 'vb1', 'pKey_c', 'vc1', 'pKey_d', 'vd1', 'pKey_e', 've1']
>>> from itertools import chain
>>> list(chain.from_iterable(item for item in sorted(d.iteritems())))
['pKey_a', 'va1', 'pKey_b', 'vb1', 'pKey_c', 'vc1', 'pKey_d', 'vd1', 'pKey_e', 've1']
>>> list(chain.from_iterable(sorted(d.iteritems())))
['pKey_a', 'va1', 'pKey_b', 'vb1', 'pKey_c', 'vc1', 'pKey_d', 'vd1', 'pKey_e', 've1']
```

Comment: @SvenMarnach: true, I'll adjust

Comment: I like the double-looping solution, it's shorter than chaining solution, and easier to understand than the other two. Your solution gets marked as the answer.

Comment: @MichaelSwartz: I'd only use the `chain.from_iterable()` if I wanted the result to be an iterable still (e.g. not call `list()` on it but just iterate over the object instead).